# how to show a list of all subsites that are under a parent subsite using Web Parts. similar to the list inside the site content

Tags: 2013, development, web-part, content-search-web-part

I have team site collection inside SharePoint 2013. Where I created a parent sub site inside it. Then under the parent sub site I created many sub sites. Now I need inside the parent sub site's home page to show a list of all the sub sites under it. now this list can be viewed from the "Site content >> Subsites", but i want to display the list in the the parent subsite home page.

I tried the following 2 approaches, but none of them worked:-

- I added a “Table of Content” web part , under the “content Rollout” Category, but the result is that all the content will be displayed , not only the sub sites, also I can not sort them by created date or show created by ..
- I added a “content Search” web part , and select “only return site” under the Keyword filter drop down as mentioned on this link ,, but nothing was displayed. here is the result i got:-

[image]

i also tried the following Query text, but did not work also.  and the ReleventResult is zero as shown below:-

[image]

So can anyone advice on this please ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following query:

```
path:"http://tdmgvst01/template" AND contentclass=STS_Web
```

Or, for the table of contents web part you could set it to only show items below "http://tdmgvst01/template", not to show pages and set the level to show to 2 for sub sites only.

Comment: Although this works, you should not promote CQWP as it's not part of the Best Practices.

Comment: @Yugo I don't mention the Content Query Web Part anywhere. Table of Contents webpart is another webpart.

Comment: Sorry for that I should have added that sadly, ToC webpart is based on CQWP.

Comment: @Yugo Ah, I did not know that, never used the table contents webpart as i prefer CSWP. Most of SharePoint OOTB webparts are pretty dull.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but doing a search this is popped up as relevant.

I found the following way to do what you are trying to achieve using CSWP and the following query:

> path:{Site} UrlDepth<4 contentclass:STS_Web

If you play with UrlDepth you can show different level of subsites. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Search Results" web part with the Query text contentclass:STS_Web Path:{SiteCollection.URL}

That works for me. I hope it works for you.